# Getting Month from date field - KDB

Tags: kdb

I have sales data stored in a database. The sales_date field contains the date on which the sale took place. I want to extract this data grouped by month, so that I will get the aggregate data for Jan, Feb, etc. Is there a way I can do this without having to extract the entire data and then doing it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work. If the data is partitioned on disk, remember to include the partition in the where clause.

```
q)tbl:([]dt:20?(2013.01.01;2013.02.01;2013.01.03);sales:20?100000)
q)select sum sales by `month$dt from tbl
dt     | sales
-------| ------
2013.01| 701075
2013.02| 298200
q)select avg sales by `month$dt from tbl
dt     | sales
-------| --------
2013.01| 50076.79
2013.02| 49700
```

Comment: Thanks, the above worked out perfectly. Also just doing
 select Sales:sum sales by salesdate.month from table also worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the simpler form:

```
q)t:([] date:10?.z.Z)                                                                   
q)select date.month from t                                                              
month  
-------
2013.10
2013.08
2004.09
2010.03
...
```